# How to separate entity object from entity framework?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

**As per my previous project architect.**

- Business Service Layer

  - Business Logic Here.
  - Can access "Entity" and "Data Access Layer"
- Data Access Layer

  - SQL Operation Made here.
  - Can access "Entity Dto"
- Entity Layer

  - All database tables Dto here.
- Presentation Layer

  - Can access Business and Entity
  - Cannot access Data Access Layer
  - View

**Now for adding Entity Framework, i want to follow same architecture.**

- Business Service Layer

  - Business Logic Here.
  - Can access "Entity" and "Data Access Layer"
- Data Access Layer

  - SQL Operation Made here.
  - Entity Framework Here(.edmx)
- Entity Layer

  - **I want to use Entity Framework classes (EntityObject) here. So no need to rewrite all DTO, but want to make sure that the CRUD should not be done by this. Should not include ObjectContext/Dbcontext**
- Presentation Layer

  - Can access Business and Entity
  - Cannot access Data Access Layer (Entity Framework)
  - View

Comment: CRUD happens when you call `dbContext.SaveChanges()`. As long as this is only done in the Data Access Layer, you should be good.

Comment: @GeorgPatscheider I mean the context should not be there..

Comment: But the context allows you to perform the sql operations. In our Architecture, we have combined the Business Layer and Data Access Layer (Business Logic works directly with the DbContext and Entities).

Answer (score 0):

There are few things I want to bring out :

1. Data Access Layer - if has dependency on edmx, then your application will be tightly coupled to use Entity Framework. If possible, Create design in such a way that DAL talks to Entity layer as abstraction without knowing which ORM is implemented underneath ( Interface based design). In future you can bring in other ORM with comparatively lesser efforts.
2. Why does Business Service Layer needs to have reference of Entity Layer. It should ideally have reference and shall be accessing only DAL.
3. Same comment as 2 for Presentation Layer.

Comment: I am accessing entity fill data in object at Presenter..-> send to business -> business do multiple business logic  forward the entity to DAL -> DAL will do CRUD..

Comment: entity means EF class or is it POCO. Presenter and Business shall not have access to EF class ideally. Atleast, Presenter shall not have it for sure.

Comment: The data access layer implementation MUST know about EF because that is its own implementation detail. Abstracting EF from the data layer makes no sense at all. Check the name of the layer: data access layer.

Comment: What if I want to change my data source from say SQL Server to Oracle later on. DAL will have reference of Entity Layer but it would more of Class/Interface dependency and not pure ORM generated Models dependency